# Image changes size and loses quality in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, image-resizing

Whenever I upload an image to my website, it makes the image a little larger than the original file has it at, plus the quality goes down as if it's zooming in or something. I tell it in the html code what the correct image size is like this:

```
img src="_images/podcast/120913_slider.png" width="851" height="323" alt="News1"
```

So the correct sizing should show, I'm not trying to change the dimensions or anything in the code. When I save the file and look at the picture, everything looks alright. But once it's in the site, it changes and I can't figure out why.

Here are two pages I'm currently working on where I see this. In the news slider on the main page, it's very clear that quality has been lost for the Christmas Novella news picture, which is obviously a problem for me.

http://thehummingbirdplace.com/

http://thehummingbirdplace.com/episode/12/9.html

I've also tried downloading the image again from the site (the "save image as" option) but it looks the same as the original image I had (smaller and high quality), so I don't understand why it displays differently on the page. I'm using Firefox, and I definitely do not have the page zoomed in or anything, I've checked. And I don't see this happening on other websites I visit, just mine, and on multiple computers, so I know there is something I must be doing wrong in the code?

I'm sorry if there is an obvious solution to this, thank you for helping!!

Update: the images show up fine in Chrome, just not Firefox it seems

Comment: Does it look the same in other browsers?

Comment: The image doesn't look bad quality nor larger than the original to me on Chrome.

Comment: Your slider images are the right size to me on firefox and chrome
851x323

Comment: I just checked on Chrome, and you're right, it's showing up fine there, so I'm not sure why it would be changed on Firefox. As I said, I saw this on two other computers, so I know it's not just mine, and made sure it is not zoomed in or anything like that

Comment: try view -> zoom -> reset

Comment: I've already tried that, I'm definitely not zoomed in. I tried both methods I know (view -> zoom -> reset and Ctrl + 0) to reset the zoom, but the webpage still views the same

Answer (score 0):

According to your link, the image on the website is exactly the image that is linked (and not resized), I can't see any difference between those. Are you sure you are exporting your images at this resolution: 851x323 ?

Comment: I double checked the files, the images are 851x323 on my computer, but they look smaller and crisper than when they show up on the website. I don't want any resizing, I just want them to display at the same size they were created at and at the same crisp quality